# How to mock statement in @PostConstruct for Groovy Spock Test Case

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have @PostConstruct in my Service class for which I am writing groovy test case. I have mocked the call inside the init() method but it doesn't work:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

private Dao testDao;
@Autowired
private AbcDao abcDao;
    
        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {        
          testDao = abcDao.findByName("testString");
          Assert.notNull(testDao, "testDao not found");
          
        } 

        public method toBeTest(){
        
        }
}
```

I have written groovy test case as:

```
public class ServiceSpec{
        
    @Autowired
    Service service
    
      def 'Test method'() {
        given:
        Dao test=new Dao()
        abcDao.findByName("testString") >>  test
      
        when:
        service.toBeTest()
        then:
        true

    }
    
    }


But it doesn't work and fail in the Assert statement.
```

Comment: This is not answering your particular question, but it's important. The code you have there is *far* away from ideal. `ServiceImpl` should have a constructor that receives the dependencies it needs rather than them being automagically injected with `@Autowired` on private fields. Using this approach allows you to unit test the class without caring for Spring. Second `@PostConstruct` is mainly available for compatibility with older (poorly designed) code, and shouldn't be used to initialise objects - that's the resposibility of the constructor.

Comment: Agreed.But the code for ServiceImpl cant be changed now due to certain reasons. Please advise if its not possible at all to fix such issue.

Comment: A general remark, not answering your question: Code can always be changed. Everything else is a pretext, especially when the reason given is just "due to certain reasons". One main reason for writing automated test is validating and improving your application design, which is much more important than just testing existing code. Test automation and especially TDD are **design tools** rather than just QA tools. QA is just a positive side effect. Testability as such is important because, if done right, it goes hand in hand with modularisation and component/dependency decoupling.